# BizTalk Null Reference Error when Editing Party Agreement Envelope Properties

Tags: biztalk, nullreferenceexception, biztalk-2016

I am using BizTalk 2016 with Feature Update 3 (CU7), and the BizTalk Server Administration Console version 3.12.774.0

- In the BizTalk Group I go to the Parties Node
- Select a Party and go to it's Agreement in the Agreements list
- Open the Agreement and go to the second tab (outgoing settings e.g. BizTalkApp->ThirdParty)
- Go to Transaction Set Settings -> Envelopes
- There is one envelope record. Go to this an change one of the values, e.g. GS4 - change from CCYYMMDD to YYMMDD
- Click Apply
- BizTalk displays the error `Object reference not set to an instance of an object. (Microsoft.BizTalk.Administration.EdiText)`

You cannot apply any changes to Envelope GS values because of this error. Changes to other agreement properties such as Interchange Settings -> Identifiers can be saved fine.

Has anyone come across this error before? How can we get past it?

Comment: There are three different FP3 version, CU5, CU6 & CU7.   Which one is installed?  3.12.774.0 is the Base BizTalk Server 2016 version.   So check in Add/Remove programs or the DLL version of the BizTalk runtime.  https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/7915.biztalk-server-versions.aspx

Comment: @Dijkgraaf it is CU7

Comment: @Dijkgraaf the Feature Update 3 version is 3.13.340.2 (CU7). Biztalk Server is listed separately to the Feature Update and is the base version 3.12.774.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that this error was caused by the fact I didn't have any value entered in the GS1 dropdown. Once I had entered this value in the row then other changes to the row could be saved.

Biztalk suspends instances of messages where the format or value of GS segments do not match those specified in the envelopes tab. So this means that I will have to analyse all the EDI documents we are receiving from our external party and make sure the GS1 values they use are covered. If there are more than one type of GS1 value used I will have to enter multiple rows in the Envelopes list.